# Send 2 parameters - FOSRestController

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am wearing the FOSRestController to create an api the only problem and wanted to send 2 parameters in the get method and i am not able to .

This and my function

```
public function getSearchAction($search, $pag)
    {
      }
```

In the router debug appears only to send 1 parameter.

[image: Hello]

Someone knows I send the 2 parameters ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your Controller?

Comment: it's all about naming your action. Try to name it "getSearchPagAction"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually does work for me. Although this didn't generate the same route as yours.

```
public function getSearchAction($search, $page)
{
}
```

Generates route:

```
get_search     GET    ANY    ANY      /whatever/{search}/search/{page}.{_format}
```

Did you clear cache before running `app/console debug:router`?

If it still doesn't work for you, there's an annotation [`FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html) to manualy setup a route:

```
/**
 * @Get("/search/{term}/{page}")
 */
public function getSearchAction(Request $request, $term, $page)
{

}
```

Which generates route:

```
get_search     GET    ANY    ANY      /whatever/search/{term}/{page}.{_format}
```